# Rails 4 wicked_pdf generate blank pdf while generating from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to save pdf on server using rails model buts its generate a blank pdf. Earlier did it in controller without problem but now its creating a blank one. Any idea What's i did wrong?

```
def generate_bulk_pdf
  view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
  view.extend(ApplicationHelper)
  view.extend(AbstractController::Rendering)
  view.extend(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers)
  students = Student.all.order('id ASC')
    students.each do | aStudent |
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
       view.render_to_string(
         :template => "#{Rails.root.join('templates/challen.pdf.erb')}",
         :locals => { '@student' => aStudent }
       )
    )
    save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea What's i did wrong? I can't find any solution

Comment: check this one `#{Rails.root.join('templates/challen.pdf.erb')}` make sure you run it on the debugger to see it point to the correct place. Also are you sure that you need this `view.extend(AbstractController::Rendering)`. Lastly I can see your template where is your Layout?

Comment: Without view.extend(AbstractController::Rendering) view.render_to_string is not working and my temple is present in the templates folder which is located in root path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good test is just put a simple line of text in your template and see if you get a PDF with that line. Strip everything back so you just generating a PDF with no coming locals, just that 1 string and let me know.

Here is how I set up mine and it works fine, it might click something :)

```
 def generate_pdf_voucher(voucher, dir_name)
    view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app/views'))
    view.class.include ApplicationHelper
    view.class.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    pdf = view.render :pdf => a_name,
                      :template => 'layouts/pdfs/voucher_pdf',
                      :layout => 'layouts/pdfs/pdf.html.erb',
                      :header => {:right => '[page] of [topage]'},
                      :locals => {:@voucher => voucher}
    # then save to a file
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf)

    save_path = Rails.root.join('public', 'pdfs', dir_name, "#{voucher[:user].id.to_s}.pdf")
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
    end
end
```

`pdf.html.erb` is the structure of the PDF
`voucher_pdf` is all the dynamic stuff

If this wasn't helpful, then put a comment on and I will delete it.

Comment: I had error: `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method host for nil:NilClass` on link_to, so I added this to fix this `view.class_eval do;
          include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers;
          self.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options
        end`